# Angular orderBy Date

Tags: javascript, date, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array which I want to order by date in Angular.js:

```
<tr ng-repeat="er in vm.readerFeeds | orderBy:'-publishedDate'">
    <td>{{er.publishedDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

The list ist not ordered right. I think the date format is the cause?

Date format is:

```
Sat, 09 Nov 2013 04:26:55 -0800
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make to `orderBy` to work you need wrap string date with object of `new Date(/**/)` in controller.

For example:

```
$scope.vm.readerFeeds = [
 {
  //.....
  publishedDate: new Date(/*your string date*/);
  },
 {
   //.....
  publishedDate: new Date(/*your string date*/);
 }
];
```

Comment: How do you do that with data from a json request? Not ideal to be modifying data clientside in the model - would be better in the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-0.9.19.min.js" ng:autobind></script>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function MainCOn() {
            this.friends = [{
                name: 'John',
                phone: '555-1212',
                age: 10,
                date: '11/02/2015'
            },
    {
        name: 'Mary',
        phone: '555-9876',
        age: 19,
        date: '11/01/2015'
    },
    {
        name: 'Mike',
        phone: '555-4321',
        age: 21,
        date: '11/04/2015'
    },
    {
        name: 'Adam',
        phone: '555-5678',
        age: 35,
        date: '11/03/2015'
    },
    {
        name: 'Julie',
        phone: '555-8765',
        age: 29,
        date: '11/05/2015'
    }];
}



        MainCOn.prototype = {

            sort: function (item) {
                if (this.predicate == 'date') {
                   var DateInNumber = item.date;
                    var day = DateInNumber.split('/')[0];
                    var month = DateInNumber.split('/')[1];
                    var year = DateInNumber.split('/')[2];
                    var monthName = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
                    var dateInAlphabatical = day + ' ' + monthName[month - 1] + ' ' + year;
                    return new Date(dateInAlphabatical);
                }
                return item[this.predicate];
            },

            sortBy: function (field) {

                if (this.predicate != field) {
                    this.predicate = field;
                    this.reverse = false;
                    console.log('f' + this.predicate + ' p' + this.reverse);
                } else {
                    this.reverse = !this.reverse;
                    console.log('else' + this.reverse);
                }
            },

            reverse: false
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng:controller="MainCOn">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <a href ng:click="sortBy('name')">Name</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href ng:click="sortBy('phone')">Phone Number</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href ng:click="sortBy('age')">Age</a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href ng:click="sortBy('date')">Date</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng:repeat="friend in friends.$orderBy(sort, reverse)">
                <td>
                    {{friend.name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{friend.phone}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{friend.age}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{friend.date}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This Code is for Order date ex :-(1/12/2015)

Comment: You should add explanation to your answer.