# AngularJS ng-repeat orderBy date not working

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a working ng-repeat, that I would like to order by descending date (newest items first).

However, I can not seem to get it to work.   I have double checked quoting, etc.   I have tried `orderBy:'createdate':reverse` , `orderBy:'article.createdate':reverse`, and `orderBy:'data.blog.article.createdate':reverse`   None seem to work.

This is my view:

```
<article data-ng-if="article.id == post || post===NULL" data-ng-repeat="article in data.blog.article | orderBy:'createdate':reverse | slice:currentPage*pageSize:currentPage+1*pageSize">
    <h2 class="blog-post-title">
        <a href="#!/blog/{{article.id}}" title="Permalink to {{article.title.__cdata}}">{{article.title.__cdata}}</a>
    </h2>
    <span class="blog-post-meta">Posted on {{article.createdate | date:'MMMM dd, yyyy h:mma'}} by {{article.author}}</span>
    <div class="blog-post-content" ng-bind-html="article.content.__cdata">{{article.content.__cdata}}</div> 
</article>
```

Here is a sample of the data (converted to JSON from XML using X2JS):

```
{
    "blog": {
        "article": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "author": "eat-sleep-code",
                "title": {
                    "__cdata": "The first article."
                },
                "content": {
                    "__cdata": "\n        This is my first article in my test site.\n      "
                },
                "createdate": "2014-05-09"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "author": "eat-sleep-code",
                "title": {
                    "__cdata": "The second article."
                },
                "content": {
                    "__cdata": "\n        This is my second article in my test site.  This article's create date is actually earlier.\n      "
                },
                "createdate": "2014-05-08"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say not working, what's happening? Are there any console errors? Are they just not in the right order?

Comment: No console errors at all.   Just not in the right order.   Oh, also tried removing the :reversed from the orderBy just to make sure that wasn't the issue.   No change.

Comment: See also this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876116/angular-orderby-date/25658846#25658846

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The `reverse` argument should be a boolean value.

Assuming you don't have reverse set to true or false somewhere in your controller, you should replace

```
orderBy:'createdate':reverse
```

with

```
orderBy:'createdate':true
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mWQ6tFxcmPkxWUuUsMju?p=preview)

[orderBy docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: The AngularJS docs in this case are nicely obfuscated. No example of simple static reverse, as is being asked about here. And in the sample they do provide, the demo variable is named the same as the keyword ('reverse') so people confuse the two. Excellent!

Comment: you can even use orderBy:'-createdate' now.