# How filter date properly with angular js by month and year

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, date

In my data base dates are arranged like below (dd/mm/yy)

```
Date
-----------
10/12/2014
22/10/2014
14/12/2015
```

I am using angularjs template and trying to sort the date field as(sorting using both month and year number) below:

```
Date
-----------
14/12/2015
10/12/2014
22/10/2014
```

But it is sorting  **ascending** as

```
Date
-----------
10/12/2014
14/12/2015
22/10/2014
```

**descending** as

```
Date
----------
22/10/2014
14/12/2015
10/12/2014
```

Here is my code

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <th>Date&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('time_stamp');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
            <th>Reference number&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('tran_id');"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
                    <td>{{data.time_stamp}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.tran_id}}</td>                
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $http.get('ajax/getCustomers.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 5; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    });
    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() { 
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

getCustomer.php:

```
$query="select tran_id,tran_type,sender,receiver,amount,fee,DATE_FORMAT(time_stamp, '%d/%m/%Y') as time_stamp,status from transaction  where sender ='demo@gmail.com' or receiver ='demo@gmail.com' order by time_stamp DESC";

//$query="select * from transaction";

$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

$arr = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row;  
    }
}
# JSON-encode the response
$json_response = json_encode($arr);

// # Return the response
echo $json_response;
```

How to obtain my desired sorting

Comment: Can you paste your JSON response please.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, [the date items are sorting like strings, not like dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876116/angular-orderby-date/19876132#19876132).

You must set them as Date objects to sort it normally.

**EDIT**

If I correctly understand your code, you are getting the data in the controller here:

```
 $http.get('ajax/getCustomers.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.list = data;
```

Following the problem diagnose, try to make something like this in the next line:

```
$scope.list.time_stamp = new Date(data.time_stamp); // convert string date to Date object
```

I didn't test the code, but I hope it works, because we know what's the problem.

***WORKING PLUNKER***

I made functional sorting date in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8FrCxfFsaZO9r1knIlVW?p=preview) based on this hypothesis and it works like a charm!

In controller I asociate the property `date` with the `Date` object like `date:new Date('9/1/2013')` and made a order like in [AngularJS sorting documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

Comment: I edited my post, hope my idea is practicaly solving that problem.

Comment: Is your success callback in JSON format, and how does it look?

Comment: i have updated my post.for your information i am using this [grid](http://www.angularcode.com/angularjs-datagrid-paging-sorting-filter-using-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: Please give me the JSON structure which contains the *time_stamp* property.

Comment: @arman1991 In your answer, isn't it supposed to supposed to be new Date instead of New Data?

Comment: OMG, yes, of course, your are right @Wayne Ellery, instead of *new Data* - new Date, my little, but in this situation, a BIG mistake in writting , I will fix it!