# Group items by month and display them in a two nested lists in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, group-by, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of items. Each item contains a `date` property.
I want to group all items by month and display them in two nested lists.

## Example

- June 2015

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
  - Item 3
- May 2015

  - Item 4
  - Item 5
  - Item 6

etc.

---

Is it possible to achieve this in Angular.js without fiddling with underlying data (i.e. via filters and such)?

I've tried the method described in this topic:
[How can I group data with an Angular filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800862/how-can-i-group-data-with-an-angular-filter), but it breaks the order of the elements and I have to manually format date to `'MMMM YYYY'` before calling `groupBy`.

Comment: It could be that your date property is in string format. Convert it into date first. To avoid duplicating, see this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734780/how-filter-date-properly-with-angular-js-by-month-and-year/27734935#27734935). Hope it will be helpfull for you.

Comment: Thank you @arman1991 for a response. My date is initially a moment() instance. I couldn't find a way to group items by month and year without first adding another property to hold textual representation of `'MMMM YYYY'`. Is there a way to use `groupby` with moment() or Date instance directly?

Comment: Maybe this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662140/using-angularjs-date-filter-with-utc-date) can help you, the moment.js is also mentioned. I find a way to group with date as described in my previous comment, but for some strange reason, the filtering doesn't work in format that you want... You will be informed if I discover a way without adding the new property :)

Comment: There is also a problem to combine grouping and ordering with date parameter...

Comment: Thank you @arman1991 for taking a time to look into this. I've decided to re-structure the data inside of my controller for now to use simpler rendering functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty straight forward, just group the items by date and display :

```
var itemsGroupedByMonth = function (items) {
    var
        groups = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],],
        itemGroupedByMonths = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      groups[items[i].date.getMonth()].push(items[i]);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
      if (groups[i].length) {
        itemGroupedByMonths.push({
          month: monthLabels[i],
          items: groups[i]
        });

      }
    }
    return itemGroupedByMonths;
  };
```

Find a working example here : http://plnkr.co/edit/idvloFKoFvWGdBSGfMsX?p=preview

Comment: How to do this with angular 2?

Comment: The solution is based on pure JS, i.e. does not use any angular component. You need to rewrite same logic in TypeScript.